# How do I use form_tag from within a helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a helper that I am using to generate a form. Parameters that are used to generate the form's fields are passed into the helper.  I can't figure out how to use the block outside of a template.

For example:

```
def generate_form(path, fields)
    form_tag(path, method: :get) do
        # what do I do in here?
    end
end
```

When I render partials within the block, nothing appears in the rendered web page.  If I join together a bunch of tags (field_tag, text_field_tag, etc.), then raw html appears on the page.

I am using Rails 3.1.0

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rails element helpers return strings, so you can do:

```
def generate_form(path, fields)
  s = form_tag(path, method: :get) do
    p = input_tag
    p << submit_tag #(everything will be wrapped in form tag)
    p #returns p from block
  end
  s.html_safe #returns s and avoids html escaping
end
```

Comment: I was unaware of safe buffers.  What was happening was I was doing an injection with a string as the initial value: fields.inject('').  I changed it to fields.inject(''.html_safe) and it works now.